# How to stop script execution

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

This script adds numbers from the array one by one, I need that when the numbers in the array run out when the button is pressed, nothing happens.

Here is codepen of my problem - https://codepen.io/Agasfer/pen/gOjMrrM

Here in the code I tried one of the termination methods but nothing works  and when the numbers in the array end with further clicks, displays undefined.

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
let currentIndex = 0;
paragraph.innerHTML = numbers[currentIndex];

let button1 = document.querySelector('button');
button1.onclick = function() {
  currentIndex += 1;
  let node = document.createTextNode(", " + numbers[currentIndex]);
  paragraph.appendChild(node);

  if (node = ", undefined") {
    event.stopPropagation()
  };

}
```

```html
<title>Hidden numbers</title>
<p></p>
<button>Show next number</button>
```

Comment: Never ever (unless you really know what you're doing) use Event.stopPropagation(). An app's layers/components (yours or third-partys) should be always aware of ongoing events in their document environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Check if `currentIndex` is at array length -1. Use `return` to prevent any further code executions (*early exit* from a function).
- Don't use `onclick` handlers unless you're creating a brand new element from in-memory. Use addEventListener() instead
- The usage of `const` might help in the long run. Use it.
- Never ever (unless you really know what you're doing) use Event.stopPropagation(). An app's layers/components (yours or third-partys) should be always aware of ongoing events in their document environment.
- It's simpler to use `textContent +=` instead of creating TextNodes

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
const button = document.querySelector('button');


let currentIndex = 0;


paragraph.innerHTML = numbers[currentIndex];

button.addEventListener("click", () => {

  if (currentIndex === numbers.length -1) return;

  currentIndex += 1;
  paragraph.textContent += ", " + numbers[currentIndex];

});
```

```html
<title>Hidden numbers</title>
<p></p>
<button>Show next number</button>
```

If you want to make the Button element *disabled* then you might not need the `return`, just add the `disabled` property on your Button element:

```js
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
const button = document.querySelector('button');


let currentIndex = 0;


paragraph.innerHTML = numbers[currentIndex];

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  currentIndex += 1;
  paragraph.textContent += ", " + numbers[currentIndex];
  if (currentIndex === numbers.length -1) {
    button.disabled = true;
  }
});
```

```html
<title>Hidden numbers</title>
<p></p>
<button>Show next number</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, Im sorry, can you explain what this line means in particular return ? if (currentIndex === numbers.length -1) return;

Comment: @Martin21 `return` will exit the function. It means that any code that is after a `return` statement will not be run. In other words: *if current index equals the length of array-1 — don't do anything* (exit the function here). Read more on [MDN: return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: well, what about where in the code it is indicated that if the array runs out of numbers, then the button should no longer be pressed?

Comment: @Martin21 the button can always be pressed. It's just that the function body will not run since the `return`. Have I understood your question correctly?

Comment: @Martin21 added another example that actually makes the Button `disabled`

Comment: Yes, when button when the button stops executing the script when clicked

Comment: Roko C. Buljan thanks, I understand everything, finally, can you explain this line? (currentIndex === numbers.length -1)

Comment: @Martin21 learn to use `console.log` In your code, before the `if` statement place: `console.log(currentIndex +' '+ numbers.length -1)`, hit the button and you'll see in the Console the output. You know what `currentIndex` is. That's the incremented index. `numbers.length` gives the `numbers` array length (`5`). Since indexes are `0`-based we use `-1` to convert it to `4`. Now, when `4 === 4` (evaluates to `true`) the `return` will kick in. Or in the second example - the button becomes disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overthinking this

```js
let numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
let currentIndex = 0;
paragraph.innerHTML = numbers[currentIndex];
let button1 = document.querySelector('button');

button1.addEventListener("click",function() {
  if (currentIndex >= numbers.length-1) return; 
  currentIndex++
  let node = document.createTextNode(", " + numbers[currentIndex]);
  paragraph.appendChild(node);
})
```

```html
<title>Hidden numbers</title>
<p></p>
<button>Show next number</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're doing perfectly fine. But in order to achieve what you want, you just need to add one condition in the button click listener, that once your `currentIndex` will be out of your array length, you will be returned from the listener.
And along with this, in order to make your code cleaner, the **below check is no longer required**.

```js
if (node = ", undefined") {
    event.stopPropagation()
};
```

So, your onclick listener will be as below

```js
button1.onclick = function(){
        if(numbers.length <= currentIndex+1)
          return;
        currentIndex+=1;
        let node  = document.createTextNode(", " + numbers[currentIndex]);
        paragraph.appendChild(node);
}
```